# GWT gridview animation

Tags: gwt

Hi i am trying to make a grid of images that scrolls in an animation similar to http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwTabLayoutPanel minus the tabs. I tried looking through the google api and search for examples but can't find anything. Can someone point me in the right direction of how to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

A. GWT animations are built into some of its panels:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels#Recipes

Scroll down to Layout Animation.

B. Use CSS3 animations:

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp